# How to use powershell to work with Matlab-generated .dat file

Tags: matlab, powershell

I need a way to programmatically work with a .dat file made in Matlab. When opened in Matlab it is a figure with some text above it, I need a number from that text so that I can manipulate it arithmetically.

Is it possible to use powershell to open the file, print it as a PDF, open it in word and grab the number? Or is there a better way to work with .dat files using PowerShell?

Comment: If you have the computer vision toolbox you could just extract the text from the image directly, see [ocr](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html)

Comment: could you provide the .dat file and the text you want to extract?

Comment: OCR isn't working due to the filetype, and I don't think the company's data security policy would allow me to provide the .dat file here